# how can update the value of null column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to create multiple bug against one project, but it show the error in edit_task_params

```
  param is missing or the value is empty: project
```

when i create the project the bug_id is null  i just want to add bug ids against the project but i don't know how can i fix this issue .

project model

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :bugs
end
```

bug model
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :project
end

bug_controller

```
class BugController < ApplicationController
    
    def new
      @bug = Bug.new
    end

    def create

      parameters = bug_params.merge({ user_id: current_user.id })   

      @bug = Bug.new(parameters)
      parameter = edit_task_params.merge({ bug_id: @bug.id })
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @project = Project.update( parameter)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @bug.save
          @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
          @project.update(edit_task_params)
          format.html { redirect_to new_bug_path, flash: { success: "bug added"} }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
        end
      end
   end

 private
 def bug_params
     params.require(:bug).permit(:title, :description, :screen_shot, :typeOf, :status_is, :deadline, :user_id, :project_id )
 end

 def edit_task_params
     params.require(:project).permit(:bug_id)
 end
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to look at whether your approach to solving the problem is good enough or not?

Why does the `Project` model need to store the `bug_id`?

To answer this, we need to think of how `one_to_many` relation works.

Let's say

- One Project has many Bugs
- Many Bugs Belongs to a Single Project

Two Approaches comes to mind

1. We should store the bugs ids to Project table| model
2. We should put project_id in bugs table | model

how it will make our Project table look like

[image: Wrong Project Table]

As you can see we have to store multiple values of bugs_ids
As a single project can have many bugs
and this structure is not recommended as it violates the first normalization. So it is ignored

Now we move towards the second way of doing this

[image: Bugs Sample Table]

[image: Porjects Table]
So we will be using this approach

Now come back to rails and your solution

1- You don't need `bug_id` in `Project` model so remove it.
2- You don't need to update `Project` while creating bug remove that part also.
3- You should not be performing update in create method which I assume you trying to do.

So after performing the necessary corrections you code would be looking like this.

```
parameters = bug_params.merge({ user_id: current_user.id })   

bug = Bug.new(parameters)
if bug.save
  format.html { redirect_to new_bug_path, flash: { success: "bug added"} }
else
  format.html { render :new }
 end
```

You can access your bugs using projects in this way

```
bugs = Project.find(project_id).bugs
```

You need to create a separate method for updating and editing.